# ORA-01031 but if I check it says that I have privileges

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
 ALTER USER SYS succeeded.
 ALTER USER SYS succeeded.

Error starting at line 11 in command:
GRANT SYSOPER TO SYS WITH ADMIN OPTION
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
           without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
           attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
           system privileges.
           When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
           if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
           than the current login.
*Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
           the required privileges.
           For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
           the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
           administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label.

Error starting at line 12 in command:
GRANT SYSDBA TO SYS WITH ADMIN OPTION
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
           without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
           attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
           system privileges.
           When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
           if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
           than the current login.
*Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
           the required privileges.
           For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
           the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
           administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label.
```

I don't understand why it gives me this error. When I check on `cmd` for privileges it says that I do have privileges and everything works perfectly. This error appears when I admin all at SYS and HR users. What should I do in this case because nothing that I've found on this whole internet can help me.

I do need this privileges because my java doesn't connect to database. Any ideas, please!

Comment: `when I check on cmd for privileges it says that I do have privileges and everything works perfect.` What works perfect? Give the command which shows that you have privileges. Also give the complete command which you are trying to run.

Comment: Don't touch `sys`! `sys` is special, leave it alone.

Comment: well......i write in cmd sqlplus / as sysdba and he get connected. when I searched for the problem they said when i write this command it must give  the error ORA-01031 if i don't have privileges.

Comment: Unless you are starting/stopping/upgrading the Oracle server, or have been asked to by Oracle Support, don't touch or even connect to the database using `sys`. It's special, it's not a normal user... stay far away from it.  Instead, use `system` (which is a DBA account) to create another user that has just the right amount of privileges for what you need, and use that to have your app connect to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ALTER USER SYS succeeded.`

Why are you altering the SYS user? The SYS account is the foundation of your database. Changing this account can do weird things to your database and interfere with the working of your application. It may also create problems if you raise issues with Oracle Support (although I suspect you don't have a contract).

> `GRANT SYSDBA TO SYS WITH ADMIN OPTION`

To repeat, why are you altering the SYS user? It is the most powerful account in the database and already has all the privileges it needs.

> "I do need this privileges because my java doesn't connect to database."

Does this mean you're trying to connect your Java application to the database using the SYS account? Hmmm, that's almost always a bad idea. Applications should use bespoke accounts with the precise set of privileges they need, not a generic account with literally complete power over the database. (Unless your application is in a special sub-set of applications for use by DBAs and expert users but - no offence intended - the nature of your question suggests you shouldn't be building one of those.)

This strikes me as [an XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
Instead of trying to mend (i.e. break) the SYS account it would be better if you addressed why your application won't connect to the database. That's the problem you really need to solve.

Comment: ok! I don't need long answers, I need solutions, so if you have any solutions will be excellent, otherwise have a good day!

Comment: @OlliePis - actually what you need is to understand **why** you are getting these error messages: it is because your application architecture is wrong. I can provide an answer if the question is answerable. At the moment the nearest  I can get to a solution is *don't do this* .

Comment: Your answer is very good! I can't understand what is wrong with my code. Why it doesn't connect to database. I made my user, to my user I granted privileges but still not working and it is a bit odd what is going on, even last time exactly the same code worked.....